# joining form:options values in form:select

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an Spring MVC 3.2.8 application based in the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework.

I have this piece of code:

```
<form:select    path="fromDeviceCountryCode"
                                        id="fromDeviceCountryCodeId"
                                        items="${euCountries}"
                                        itemValue="code"
                                        itemLabel="description"
                                        cssClass="c-select form-control"                                        
                                        onchange="javascript:updateDevice();">

                            <form:option value="0" label="Please Select" />
                            <form:options items="${euCountries}"    itemValue="code" itemLabel="description"/>
                            <form:option value="0" label="------------------ non EU countries ------------------" />
                            <form:options items="${nonEuCountries}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="description"/>

                        </form:select>
```

But in the JSP I don't have the values of `${nonEuCountries}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have 2 times the tag  this generates de problem.

You could try to solve this with a different approach:

```
<form:select path="fromDeviceCountryCode"
      id="fromDeviceCountryCodeId"
      items="${euCountries}"
      itemValue="code"
      itemLabel="description"
      cssClass="c-select form-control"    
      onchange="javascript:updateDevice();">
          <form:option value="0" label="Please Select" />
          <c:forEach var="european" items="${euCountries}">
                <form:option value="${european.code}" label="${european.description}"/>
          </c:forEach> 
          <form:option value="0" label="------------------ non EU countries ------------------" />
          <c:forEach var="nonEuropean" items="${nonCountries}">
               <form:option value="${nonEuropean.code}" label="${nonEuropean.description}"/>
          </c:forEach> 
     </form:select>
```